# Scala if-else efficiency improvements

Tags: performance, scala, if-statement

The following snippet is invoked few million times in an application,

```
val res = myArray.map { case (expr1,expr2) =>
  val nan1 = expr1.isNaN
  val nan2 = expr2.isNaN

  if (nan1 && nan2) 0.0
  else if (nan1  && !nan2) expr2
  else if (!nan1 && nan2) expr1
  else expr1-expr2
}
```

where `myArray` often contains between 100 and 1000 pairs.

Is there a way to make it (even) faster ?

Comment: I think the main performance sinks are not if/else statements, but usage of map and pattern matching (given that expr* are not heavy)

Comment: To build on what om-nom-nom said, if you rewrite this with a `while` loop instead of using `map` you could also break `myArray` into two separate arrays rather than using an array holding tuples. This gets rid of the level of indirection through the tuples.

Comment: Maybe try `myArray.par.map { ... }`

Comment: @wingedsubmariner please consider this comment as an answer for up-voting :) many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is *the* performance bottleneck, consider using a pair of arrays of the respective primitive type (`Double`?) over an array of pairs, and write a good old `while` loop, as  @wingedsubmariner suggested.

To answer your original question, assuming that NaNs are rare, you can get marginal speedup by reordering the if-elses so as to identify the most common case first, not least because of branch prediction:

```
if (!nan1 && !nan2) expr1-expr2
else if (nan1) if (!nan2) expr2 else 0.0
else expr1
```

or maybe:

```
if (!nan1)
  if (!nan2) expr1-expr2 else expr1
else 
  if (!nan2) expr2 else 0.0
```

But you may have to reduce this snippet to a microbenchmark and measure it using something like [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) to notice the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave out `&&!nan2` and `!nan1 &&`, since you are already sure that not both are true (tested above). However, the optimizer might notice this too and remove the code for you, so I doubt it would impact performance.